# jQuery Dropdown - Follow URL onchange

Tags: jquery

I have a select element that functions as a dropdown menu. Each option has a value that is a URL.

I want it so that every time any option is selected, the page will go to that option's value as a URL.

This is what I have so far, but I am not sure if I am on the right track:

```
$('userNav').change(function() {
        window.location.replace("http://" something with concatenation);
    });
```

Any help?

Comment: please use more self explanatory titles for your questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#userNav').change(function() {
     window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

**Online demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/amosrivera/Cg2yv/

Comment: No need to wrap `this` in a jQuery object. `this.value` would work just as well.

Comment: Right thanks, i just like to have consistency, go with the jQuery syntax if i'm using jQuery as long as that doesn't hurt performance.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code its working grt..**

```js
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

    $("#submit").hide();

    $("#page-changer select").change(function() {
        window.location = $("#page-changer select option:selected").val();
    })

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['nav'])) {
   header("Location: $_POST[nav]");
 }
?>
<form id="page-changer" action="" method="post">
    <select name="nav">
        <option value="">Go to page...</option>
        <option value="http://css-tricks.com/">CSS-Tricks</option>
        <option value="http://digwp.com/">Digging Into WordPress</option>
        <option value="http://quotesondesign.com/">Quotes on Design</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```